# Angular routing: 3 level hierarchy - parent child child

Tags: angular, routes, nested, parent-child, multi-level

- App component (router-outlet)

  - Parent 1 ---- Level 1

    - Child 1 ---- Level 2

      - Child 1 ---- Level 3
      - Child 2 ---- Level 3
      - Child 3 ---- Level 3

This is the scenario for the nested routing in my angular project. So, my question is Level 3 nesting possible in angular cause I have already tried to access level three child but it's not working.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'Parent1/Child1', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'Parent1', component: Parent1Component,
    children: [
      { path: 'Child1', component: Child1Component },
      { path: 'Child2', component: Child2Component },
      { path: 'Child3', component: Child3Component },
      { path: 'Child4', component: Child4Component },
      { path: 'Child5', component: Child5Component },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'Parent2', component: Parent2Component,
  },
  {
    path: 'Parent3', component: Parent3Component,
  },
  {
    path: 'Parent4', component: Parent4Component,
  },
  {
    path: 'Parent5', component: Parent5Component,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'Child1', component: Child1Component,
        children: [
          { path: 'Child1', component: Child1Component },
          { path: 'Child2', component: Child2Component },
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Parent1>Child1 are working properly.**

**Parent5>Child1>Child1 are not working.**

Comment: can you please make a stackblitz example. just want to know how you are redirecting/calling different routes relative to whitch path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that nested routes, you just need to add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your Child1Component